# Overriding a CNAME within a CNAME chain works on Ubuntu but not Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dns, hosts-file, cname

Best practices aside (not having CNAME chains), I am curious to know why this is happening.

I have the following:

CNAME subdomain.example.com -> CNAME other.example.com -> A 172.17.0.1

If I wanted to override other.example.com, I thought I could edit /etc/hosts (or hosts file on windows) with the following:

172.18.144.1 other.example.com

On Ubuntu 18.04, I get the following:

```
$ ping subdomain.example.com
PING other.example.com (172.18.144.1)
$ ping other.example.com
PING other.example.com (172.18.144.1)
```

Which is what I expected.

But on Windows, I get:

```
> ping subdomain.example.com
Pinging other.example.com [172.17.0.1]
> ping other.example.com
Pinging other.example.com [172.18.144.1]
```

It seems like the hosts file is not referenced after the first resolution of the domain in the chain.

What is happening here and what can I do to be able to override other.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

It is not "not best practice", it isn't allowed. Period.

I.e., it can break in endearing ways, depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Regardless, I am curious to know technically why it is happening to gain a better understanding.